# Threadripper 1950x random system hangups - How can I track the problem?

Tags: 16.04, freeze, amd-processor

Short introduction: I have made a mistake and bought the next new thing (for the first time in my life) which makes me a paying beta tester (unfortunately). I have already scoured through everywhere on the internet.

My problem is the following: When I'm using the browser on any other application I get very short freezes on those apps (1-5 seconds, sometimes 10-15s)

My system configuration is the following:

- Threadripper 1950x
- MSI X399 gaming pro
- Kingston 2x16gb 2133mhz RAM
- NVIDIA 1080 ti

Things I have tried:

- updated to 4.17 kernel (no difference on the behavior)
- added `pcie_aspm=off` to solve the PCIe Bus error [PCI Bus Errors](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/threadripper-pcie-bus-errors/118977/24)
- ran [stress test ng](https://github.com/ColinIanKing/stress-ng)
- ran memtest
- switched SSD
- test each individual RAM module
- reinstalled ubuntu
- tried a different PSU
- tried different NVIDA drivers with/without CUDA
- went through syslog, kern.log, desmeg (the only interesting thing I can find):

`Jun 23 04:28:33 vanila kernel: [   19.244589] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth18d1bdd: link becomes ready
Jun 23 04:28:33 vanila kernel: [   19.244631] br-1dbd07f6e628: port 3(veth18d1bdd) entered blocking state
Jun 23 04:28:33 vanila kernel: [   19.244633] br-1dbd07f6e628: port 3(veth18d1bdd) entered forwarding state
Jun 23 04:28:33 vanila NetworkManager[1405]: <info>  [1529724513.8132] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth249d03f, iface: veth249d03f)
Jun 23 04:28:33 vanila NetworkManager[1405]: <info>  [1529724513.8132] device (veth249d03f): driver 'veth' does not support carrier detection.
Jun 23 04:28:33 vanila NetworkManager[1405]: <info>  [1529724513.8134] device (veth18d1bdd): link connected
Jun 23 04:28:41 vanila gnome-session-binary[3683]: Entering running state
Jun 23 04:36:22 vanila kernel: [  487.292420] zram: Added device: zram0
Jun 23 04:36:22 vanila kernel: [  487.340465] zram0: detected capacity change from 0 to 68719476736
Jun 23 04:36:23 vanila kernel: [  487.934775] EXT4-fs (zram0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
Jun 23 04:46:18 vanila kernel: [ 1082.725056] perf: interrupt took too long (2631 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 76000
Jun 23 04:50:37 vanila kernel: [ 1341.746646] perf: interrupt took too long (3303 > 3288), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 60500
Jun 23 04:51:43 vanila NetworkManager[1405]: <info>  [1529725903.8403]   address 192.168.1.85
Jun 23 04:51:43 vanila NetworkManager[1405]: <info>  [1529725903.8411]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jun 23 04:51:43 vanila NetworkManager[1405]: <info>  [1529725903.8414]   gateway 192.168.1.254
Jun 23 04:51:43 vanila NetworkManager[1405]: <info>  [1529725903.8416]   server identifier 192.168.1.254
Jun 23 04:51:43 vanila NetworkManager[1405]: <info>  [1529725903.8418]   lease time 3600
Jun 23 04:51:43 vanila NetworkManager[1405]: <info>  [1529725903.8421]   nameserver '192.168.1.254'
Jun 23 04:51:43 vanila NetworkManager[1405]: <info>  [1529725903.8423]   domain name 'lan'
Jun 23 04:51:43 vanila NetworkManager[1405]: <info>  [1529725903.8425] dhcp4 (enp8s0): state changed bound -> bound
Jun 23 04:56:01 vanila kernel: [ 1666.229322] perf: interrupt took too long (4136 > 4128), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 48250`

I'm almost positive this has something to do with the docker veth so I think this output is useless.
The `zram0` and `interrupt took too long` and probably from [ryzen-test](https://github.com/suaefar/ryzen-test) which I was running at the moment to make another stress test

At this moment I'm thinking about selling the system. I have no more ideas on how to deal with this and I need a powerful server for my research. This is wearing me out.

Is there anything else I can do to try to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the solution

Disable C sleep States (deep sleep) and AMD cool'n'quiet in the BIOS